# Constructor and initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, initializer-list

Could somebody tell me the theory behind this?

Why the last call doesn't compile?

> test.cc: In function ‘int main()’: test.cc:15:12: error: too many braces around initializer for ‘int’ [-fpermissive] test.cc:15:12:
>
> error: invalid conversion from ‘’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive] test.cc:9:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void f(std::initializer_list)’ [-fpermissive] test.cc:15:12:
>
> error: aggregate value used where an integer was expected

I think either c++11 or g++ 4.7 is broken on this.
Thank you!

```
#include <initializer_list>

class A { 
  public:
  A(const std::initializer_list<int>) {}
};

void f(const std::initializer_list<int>) {}

int main() {
  A({1});  // Compile OK
  f({1});  // Compile OK
  A({{{1}}});   // Compile OK
  //f({{{1}}}); // Compile Error.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm talking about the stardard header initializer_list in c++11.

Comment: Interesting. Clang just throws a warning about extra braces in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I believe GCC is thinking.

This is your program with 1 extra line, and the interesting lines numbered.

```
int main() {
  A({1});  // 1. Compile OK
  f({1});  // 2. Compile OK
  A{{1}};  // 3. Compile OK, equivalent to 1. 
  A({{{1}}});   // 4. Compile OK
  //f({{{1}}}); // 5. Compile Error.
}
```

Why does GCC compile 4 but not 5?

For clarity, suppose the construction at #4 actually declared something:

```
A a{{{1}}};   // 4a. Compile OK
```

GCC asks if the argument of the constructor, which is `{{1}}` is 
implicitly convertible to `A`. So is:

```
A{{1}}
```

a valid conversion from `{{1}}` to `A`? Yes it is - as per 3.

This reasoning, of course, is not applicable to #5; hence error.

If you want to stop GCC from accepting #4, then block the
enabling conversion by making the enabling constructor explicit:

```
class A { 
    public:
    explicit A(const std::initializer_list<int> il) {}
};
```

Then #4 will give the error:

```
error: converting to ‘A’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)’
```

Comment: I noticed that f({1}) and f({{1}}) both compile without error. what is the difference between them?

Comment: My clumsy account of the constructor conversion from `{{1}}` hits the board somewhere but Johannes gets the cigar. I think his words "the second goes to the initializer list recursively."
probably also explain why `f({{1}})` is OK. But I'll defer to him on that.

Comment: The first brace is for the init list. The second brace is for the int.

Answer (score 2):

A {1} can initialize an int. A {{1}} probably should not - there is a defect report on tbe committee for that. GCC forbids that and clang just tends to emit warnings about redundant braces currently.

When X is a class that has copy or move constructors, then X ({...}) may invoke invoke one of them. Notice that X {...} may too, but is restricted to not allow user defined conversions (for a copy or move constructor).

Now with your A ({{{1}}}) the first brace is consumed by the copy/move constructor. The second goes to the initializer list recursively. And the third goes to the contained int.

According to the Standard, adding one more brace will break for A ({{{{1}}}}). Because the second brace would need to be consumed by a copy/move constructor of A but need a user defined conversion sequence. The same holds for A {{{{1}}}}, which is invalid for this reason too.